# Issue extending Animation class in Android

Tags: android, animation, subclass

I am trying to create a custom animation extending `Animation` class, and I am getting an unexpected error.

First I had the following:

```
 Animation animation =  AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.circle_anim);
```

After that I created my `CustomAnimation` class like the following

```
public class CustomAnimation extends Animation {

public CustomAnimation() {
}

public CustomAnimation(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

// more code for the class here...
```

}

So now I use the animation like this:

```
   CustomAnimation animation = (CustomAnimation) AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.circle_anim);
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.animation.AnimationSet cannot be cast to com.example.userRand.Newapp.Model.CustomAnimation
```

How should I extend the `CustomAnimation` class to make it work?

Comment: not sure  ```AnimationUtils.loadAniation``` is the right way to instantiate CustomAnimation class, but you could try `new CustomAnimation`  and load resource from constructor .

Comment: yeah I think the same...not sure if that is correct....but, since it worked with `Animation` and `CustomAnimation` extends from `Animation` I assumed it should work....maybe I am getting it wrong.